# lua: pattern matching and extracting a phone number

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I am having trouble crafting a function that has the following requirements in Lua:

- Takes a string `phone_number` and 2-digit `country_code` as input.
- `phone_number` has the form {1 || ""}{`country_code`}{10 or 11-digit mobile number}

I need as output the 10 or 11-digit mobile number.

Example I/O:

`phone_number`= "552234332344", `country_code`= "55" => "2234332344"

`phone_number`= "15522343323443", `country_code`= "55" => "22343323443"

Thanks!

Comment: elaborate the exact pattern of country code and phone no.

Comment: @coosal added some examples. Thanks!

Comment: Capturing only what you need and discarding the 1: `code, number = phone_number:match('1?(%d%d)(%d+)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `"(1?)(%d%d)(%d+)"`. Using this with your examples:

```
print(("15522343323443"):match("(1?)(%d%d)(%d+)"))
print(("5522343323443"):match("(1?)(%d%d)(%d+)"))
```

will print:

```
1   55  22343323443
55  22343323443
```

If you need exactly 10 or 11 digits in the phone number, then specify `%d` 10 times and then add `%d?`. `%d` is a character class that matches any number and question mark modifier matches the previous character or a character class 0 or 1 time.

Comment: great! Noob question: how do I get the third return value (the number)?

Comment: Got it, it's: 
> a,b,c=string.match("15522343323443","(1?)(%d%d)(%d+)")
> =c

Comment: or just group the elt you need: return string.match("15522343323443","1?%d%d(%d+)")

Comment: @Neil, exactly; either of those methods will do

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
^[0-9]{1,3}\s\|{2}\s[0-9]{10,11}$
```

This expression is for pattern like `1 || 9945397865` like you asked i guess . .

**EDITED:** I guess this works

- fetch string length using `string.len('552234332344')` => *Output:* 12
- match string using  `string.match ('552234332344', ^%d)` => *Output:* 552234332344 if matches
- fetch country code using `string.sub ('552234332344', 1, 2)` => *Output:* 55
- fetch phone no. using `string.sub('552234332344', 3)` => *Output:* 2234332344

Comment: What's the lua-compatible version? i.e. using patterns (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)

Comment: That's a regular expression; not a lua pattern.

Comment: @daurnimator read the whole answer before you respond bro . . i guess you missed the edited answer . . :)

Comment: the edited answer is rather unclear though.... you also missed the fact you could do: `%d%d?%d?` to replicate the behaviour of {1,3}.

Comment: @daurnimator while coding you need to make some shortcut ways . . think about less execution time . . `{1,3}` gets rendered much faster than `%d%d%d` . . Everybody can code . . but nobody thinks about the execution time . . :)